# mysql delete from table based on select from table

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling with what I thought would be simple.
I need to delete some duplicate rows that got created in a table following the release of some buggy code.

The query I've tried is as follows:

```
delete from buzz where id IN (select distinct b1.id from buzz b1, buzz b2 where b1.id != b2.id and b1.message = b2.message);
```

The select definitely selects the correct ids that I want to delete, however I get the error

ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'buzz' for update in FROM clause

I've tried every different thing that I can think of, so now I'm thinking I'm just approaching this the wrong way.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really don't need a subquery for this. This should work:

```
DELETE b1
FROM buzz b1,
     buzz b2
WHERE b1.id > b2.id
  AND b1.message = b2.message;
```

This deletes the duplicates but leaves the original in the table.

Comment: All of these solutions were great, but this was perfect for our needs since it was useful to leave the original in place.

Comment: although, I should add you need to use "distinct b1" or you get lots of duplicate ids.

Answer (score 0):

There is a little trick to work-around the issue in MySQL. It works on MySQL 5.6 at list, just wrap the sub-select with another one sub-select:

```
delete from buzz where id IN (select * from 
(select distinct b1.id from buzz b1, buzz b2 where b1.id != b2.id 
and b1.message = b2.message) Tab_alias);
```

Also you can refer to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
delete from buzz where id IN (
  select id  from (
      select distinct b1.id
      from buzz b1, buzz b2 
      where b1.id != b2.id 
      and b1.message = b2.message) 
   as tempTable);
```